# Different methods to compute a unitary representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, harmonic-analysis

Given a nilpotent Lie group $G$ (for example the Heisenberg group), what is the most effective method to calculate their unitary representation:

- The orbit method due to Kirillov; or
- The induction procedure due to Mackey.

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the most effective method is, but there are certainly algorithms available for computing unitary irreducible representations of a nilpotent Lie group. For the orbit method there are in particular algorithms to compute polarizing subalgebras (e.g., Vergne polarizing subalgebras) subordinated to a linear functional in the linear dual of the corresponding nilpotent Lie algebra. This is an important step already, and quite challenging in general, from a computational viewpoint. The programs have first been developed by Niels Pederson in REDUCE, and later by Vignon Oussa in MATHEMATICA.